# how to send int instead of string jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that gets a 5 digits value on a string, but i need to send it as an int, i have tried the `.toInt()` but it seems that is not working for some reason, this is my code

```
@Composable
fun ParentConfirmScreen(
    onConfirm: (Int) -> Unit,
    registerUiState: RegisterScreenUiState,
    navigateTo: (String) -> Unit,
    goBack: () -> Unit,
) {
 var pinValue by remember { mutableStateOf("")}
            PinView(pinText = pinValue ,
                onValueChange ={pinValue = it},
                type = PIN_VIEW_TYPE_BORDER )

SecondaryButton(
                text = "Continuar",
                modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .testTag(PARENT_PROFILE_BTN_TEST_TAG),
                enabled = true
                ) {
                    onConfirm (pinValue.toInt())
                }
             }
        }
    }
}


const val PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE = 0
const val PIN_VIEW_TYPE_BORDER = 1

@Composable
fun PinView(
    pinText: String,
    onValueChange:(String)-> Unit,
    digitColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    digitSize: TextUnit = 30.sp,
    containerSize: Dp = digitSize.value.dp * 2,
    digitCount: Int = 5,
    type: Int = PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE,
) {
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = pinText,
            onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            decorationBox = {
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
                    repeat(digitCount) { index ->
                        DigitView(index, pinText, digitColor, digitSize, containerSize, type = type)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun DigitView(
    index: Int,
    pinText: String,
    digitColor: Color,
    digitSize: TextUnit,
    containerSize: Dp,
    type: Int = PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE,
) {
    val modifier = if (type == PIN_VIEW_TYPE_BORDER) {
        Modifier
            .width(containerSize)
            .padding(bottom = 3.dp)
    } else Modifier.width(containerSize)

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Text(
            text = if (index >= pinText.length) "" else pinText[index].toString(),
            color = digitColor,
            modifier = modifier,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            fontSize = digitSize,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        if (type == PIN_VIEW_TYPE_BORDER) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
            Divider(
                Modifier
                    .width(50.dp)
                    .padding(bottom = 2.dp, top = 5.dp)
                    .offset(y = -10.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                thickness = 1.dp)
        }
    }
}
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does `PinView` and `DigitView` have to do with `MyTextField`? and what is "not working"?

Comment: ooh, im dumb and forgot to edit that, the my text is gone now, what doesnt work is in secondary botton this section `onConfirm (myText.toInt())` it still sending ints instead of an int

Comment: Looks like you need to take some rest,` myText` is not being called anywhere aside from `onConfirm (myText.toInt())}` based on your edited question.

Comment: edited again to `onConfirm (pinValue.toInt())`, srry its been a long night and this is driving me crazy

Comment: Now I'm able to run 90% of your pasted code, with my own  `Button()` implementation, and its working, `onConfirm (pinValue.toInt())` is called when I used `ParentConfirmScreen` outside, so it looks like an `onClick` is not being triggered somewhere in your `SecondaryButton`, I can't guess what's inside of it or how it is implemented, and I still don't know what is "not working"..

Comment: i havent checked the button component gonna do that thanks, the problem for me is that let say that you input 56786, when you click the button you send "56786" as a string i need to send 56786 as an int, thats why i put the `.toInt()`

Comment: I don't want us to get flagged, so I'll have my last comment.  You have a param `onConfirm: (Int) -> Unit`, which is a lambda that accepts an `int`, when you call it `pinValue.toInt()` its already converted to an `int` type so I'm not sure what problem you are having. Try to do some arithmetic on it inside the lambda callback scope and see you can verify its already an `int` type, ill post an answer for you to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stripped things down and I'm still not sure what is "not working" but calling

```
pinValue.toInt()
```

converts a number String representation to an Int value.

Your `ParentConfirmScreen` composable (removed unnecessary codes)

```
@Composable
fun ParentConfirmScreen(
    onConfirm: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    var pinValue by remember { mutableStateOf("")}

    Button(
        onClick = {
            onConfirm(pinValue.toInt())
        }
    ){}
}
```

and its usage outside

```
setContent {
       ParentConfirmScreen(
           onConfirm = { pinAsInteger ->
              // its already an integer here, and you can perform number operations on it
              Log.e("LogTag", "${pinAsInteger * 10 / 2 % 200}")
           }
       )
}
```

Comment: yeah, my problem was on the responsemodel, thanks for the help

Comment: Did it work? I'm not sure if I contributed anything to it, up until now I didn't know what is "not working",  I was just about to update my answer to verify that `pinValue` is being converted to Int, though I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: @user10625391 One more thing to add to this, it will be better to add check for if the input is not null and empty and digits only. It will be wise to use `isDigitsOnly()` or passing null value in onConfirm lambda with `toIntOrNull` so that the crash will not happen.